# Why do I get empty graph when adding 'Abs' function?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Can someone be so nice to provide some help for this particular situation? I try to plot a graph of a derivative which contains modulus. Without it the graph is drawn correctly:

[image: correct graph]

But when I wrap the expression in the `Abs` *Mathematica* outputs an empty graph:

[image: empty graph]

I looked for several answers related to empty graphs, but nothing seems to fit to my case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Workaround: `With[{a = Piecewise[{{#, # >= 0}, {-#, # < 0}}, 0] &}, Plot[Evaluate[D[a[5 - 2 x], x]], {x, -1*^3, 1*^3}, Axes -> None, PlotRange -> {-1*^3, 1*^3}]]`

Comment: @J. M, thank you, it works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Might it be the way *Mathematica* deals with the derivative of `Abs[]`?  For example,

```
D[Abs[5 - 2 x], x]
```

returns

```
-2*Derivative[1][Abs][5 - 2*x]
```

Try

```
Plot[Evaluate[D[Sqrt[(5 - 2 x)^2], x]], {x, -10, 10}]
```

Comment: I was about to say that, so I added the relevant example to your answer. +1

Answer (score 7):

I'm also wondering why *Mathematica* doesn't treat the derivative of `Abs` as normal way. But here is a solution.

```
Plot[Evaluate@ComplexExpand[D[Abs[5 - 2 x], x]], {x, -10, 10}]
```

Comment: "I'm also wondering..." - that *Mathematica* considers variables to take complex values by default is a hint...

Comment: Perhaps not everyone knows that as a function of a complex variable, `Abs[z]` is not differentiable at any `z`.

Comment: @J.M. Yes. Sometimes if plotting a complex function carelessly , _Mathematica_ will return a empty graphic. I think in this occasion, it will be helpful if _Mathematica_ give some warnings.

Comment: @MichaelE2 _Mathematica_ often tells me to rethink about the complex variables:)

Answer (score 5):

As of V11.1, another available approach is to use `RealAbs` instead of `Abs`:

```
Plot[Evaluate[D[RealAbs[5 - 2 x], x]], {x, -10, 10}]
```

Note that `Abs`, as a function of a complex variable, is not differentiable, which I mentioned in [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24873/why-do-i-get-empty-graph-when-adding-abs-function#comment77100_24897) earlier.

Comment: This solved my issue, thanks