# Removing Abs with `ComplexExpand` not working

Tags: complex

Here is what I have used for this.
From this link, [Why do I get empty graph when adding 'Abs' function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24873/why-do-i-get-empty-graph-when-adding-abs-function#24897)
I know that I can remove `Abs` with `ComplexExpand`

**Input**

```
ComplexExpand[Sqrt[1 - Abs[x]^2]]
```

**Output**

```
((1 - x^2)^2)^(1/4) Cos[1/2 Arg[1 - Abs[x]^2]] + 
 I ((1 - x^2)^2)^(1/4) Sin[1/2 Arg[1 - Abs[x]^2]]
```

*However, it works just fine when I use `Plus` in the `Sqrt`.*

**Input**

```
ComplexExpand[Sqrt[1 + Abs[x]^2]]
```

**Output**

```
Sqrt[1 + x^2]
```

**Is there anyone who can explain this?**

Comment: Maybe you can try setting the option `TargetFunctions->{Re, Im}` to `ComplexExpand`?

Comment: Documentation says `ComplexExpand` assumes all variables are real. Since your example doesn't work, perhaps they missed a case. Or you can use `Simplify[Sqrt[1+ Abs[x]^2],Element[x,Reals]]` which works with both `+` and `-` and get on with the work you need to do.

Comment: @QuantumDot, your method is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe adding `Simplify` gives you what you want.

```
ComplexExpand[Sqrt[1 - Abs[x]^2]] // Simplify
(*Piecewise[{{I*((x^2 - 1)^2)^(1/4), Abs[x] > 1}}, ((x^2 - 1)^2)^(1/4)]*)
```

or

```
$Assumptions = -1 < x < 1

ComplexExpand[Sqrt[1 - Abs[x]^2]] // Simplify
(*Sqrt[1 - x^2]*)
```

The plus case is different because the value inside the `Sqrt` is always positive.  It is generally a good idea to add `Simplify` to any result `ComplexExpand` returns.

Comment: I think there is no need to add `ComplexExpand`.  You pan get the same result with only `Simplify` used here